# unable to use jquery while using jquery-steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I'm using jquery-steps in my shopping checkout page and it works fine but i am unable to use jquery to get elements inside the form to dynamically change the price based on the quantity.I cant anyone help?

i initialize the wizard by the code below but when i use other jquery code to like

```
$(".remove > div").click(function() {
```

it will not work

**JS**

```
<script>
        var form = $(".shopping-cart");
            form.children("div").steps({
                headerTag: ".header-tags",
                bodyTag: "section",
                transitionEffect: "fade",
                onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
                  if (currentIndex > newIndex)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
                    return form.valid();
                },
                onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {
                    form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
                    return form.valid();
                },
                onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
                    alert("Submitted!");
                }
            });
```

Comment: please, provide error message from console

Comment: What does `console.log( $(".remove > div") );` output?

Comment: Are you dynamically creating those divs you're trying to bind the event to? You could also post your HTML markup so we have the bigger picture.

Comment: can you show us the order in which you load your scripts? you should load jquery first.

Comment: I mean information from from Developer Tools>Console. https://monosnap.com/file/QASmzCFhWloxEEx8C7MRcgZ606Wgaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
$( ".shopping-cart" ).on( "click", ".remove > div", function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer and i also faced another problem with jquery-steps i want to use dropzone.js for drag and drop but i am unable to use it inside the wizard can you help me on that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use form id instead of class.
Instead of

```
var form = $(".shopping-cart");
```

use

```
var form = $("#your-shopping-cart-id");
```

Also documentation contains a lot useful [examples](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples);